# Intel core i7 4th gen dont use turbo boost

Tags: windows-7, cpu, bios, intel-core-i7, turbo-boost

I have a laptop ASUS ROG G751JL.
When I bought it, there is Windows 10 installed.
Since I formatted it and installed Windows 7.

The processor is Intel Core i7 4th generation.
It should have the turbo boost technology. 
Here is the [laptop specification](https://www.asus.com/us/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G751JL/specifications/).

I usually get processor up to 3.6Ghz when I plug the laptop to sector.
But now, It stuck to 2.4Ghz.

It seems like tu turbo boost isn't active at all.
I cant find a way to check what's wrong.
In my BIOS, there is no option to configure turbo boost. I already have updated my BIOS firmware to the latest from the Asus product support page.
I don't have the Asus BIOS.

How can I fix that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you cleaned in the inside of the device?

Comment: If you mean clean the laptop by unmount it. Yes I did it.

Comment: So you found the family of dust bunnies a new home?

Comment: Sry im not sure to understand what you asking.

Comment: Turbo Boost is only available when your CPU is cool. When the CPU heats up, no Turbo Boost. See https://www.thewindowsclub.com/intel-turbo-boost-technology-max

Comment: @fliim - What did you clean exactly about your device.  Be specific

Comment: I just clean the keyboard and then some dust.